# Enabling a submit button AFTER verification of image/height and width are done

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I have the following code to check to see if the dimensions and size of selected pictures are within certain constraints. The submit button is disabled until all images are verified to be within the constraints.

The one issue I have is that because it may take a bit longer to verify the width and height of a picture it might enable the button before the last image is verified. I have marked these two sections with comments in the code below.

How can I make sure that the "Problem line" is not encountered until the image width/height has been verified?

```
$('#file').change(function(){
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var image, file;
var fileArray = this.files;
var numfiles = fileArray.length;
var img = new Image();
var allgood = true;
var error = "";

for (var i=0; i< numfiles; i++)
{
    file = fileArray[i];
    size = Math.round(file.size / 1024);
    name = file.name;

    if (size > 50){
        allgood = false;
        error = "Your image " + name + " is too big (> 50KB)";
    }

    img.onload = function(){
        width = img.width;
        height = img.height;
        if (width != 300 || height != 200){
            /***** This might not get done in time *****/
            allgood = false;
            error += "Your image " + name + " is not 300px x 200px";
        }
    }
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);

    if (!allgood){
        break;
    }


}
if (!allgood){
    $('#error').html(error);
} else {
    /***** Problem line *****/
    $('#upload').prop("disabled", false);
}
});
```

Note: #file refers to the HTML input element of type file with the multiple attribute set, #upload refers to the submit button with disabled attribute set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:-

```
$('#file').change(function(){
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var image, file;
var fileArray = this.files;
var numfiles = fileArray.length;
var img = new Image();
var allgood = true;
var error = "";

var totalLoaded = 0;

for (var i=0; i< numfiles; i++)
{
    file = fileArray[i];
    size = Math.round(file.size / 1024);
    name = file.name;

    if (size > 50){
        allgood = false;
        error = "Your image " + name + " is too big (> 50KB)";
    }

    img.onload = function(){
        totalLoaded++;
        width = img.width;
        height = img.height;
        if (width != 300 || height != 200){
            /***** This might not get done in time *****/
            allgood = false;
            error += "Your image " + name + " is not 300px x 200px";
        }

        if(totalLoaded == numFiles){
           if (!allgood){
              $('#error').html(error);
           } else {
              /***** Problem line *****/
              $('#upload').prop("disabled", false);
           }
       }
    }
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);

}
});
```

count each time a image is loaded and only call the `allgood` check when all are finished.

**EDIT**

If you want to exit on a fail, you could try something like this:-

```
$('#file').change(function(){
    loadImage(this.files, 0);
});

function loadImage(array, index){
    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var file = fileArray[i];
    var size = Math.round(file.size / 1024);
    var name = file.name;

    if (size > 50){
        $('#error').html("Your image " + name + " is too big (> 50KB)");
        return;
    }

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;

        if (width != 300 || height != 200){
            $('#error').html("Your image " + name + " is not 300px x 200px");
            return;
        }

        if(index == (array.length-1)){
          $('#upload').prop("disabled", false);
          return;
        }

        loadImage(array, index++);
    }

    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
}
```

Comment: Okay, that does look like it will work. The only problem is that it will continue looping even if the first one is detected bad. It might not be a big issue though as it is executed on the user machine so shouldn't be too slow.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will need to take a look at this tomorrow. I see one issue with this line: "fileArray[i]" though I'm assuming I'll just change this to "array[index]"

Comment: ahhh course. I just wrote this without testing but it gives you an idea of how to go about it.

Comment: One other thing I had to change was changing index++ to ++index